# Changing a character in a word within a string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have the following dataframe:

```
description
#voice-artist,#creative-director
#designer,#asistant
```

I would like to to replace # with "" and "," with ", "

I do the following but it does not work i.e. I get the same string

```
df["description"] = df["description"].str.replace("#", "")
df["description"] = df["description"].str.replace(",", ", ")
```

How can I get what I want?

Comment: What did you mean “.str”?

Comment: your code work for me ~

Comment: It should work, what is the error you do get?

Comment: For some reason, I get the exact same string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `regex`?

**Sample DF:**

```
>>> df
                        description
0  #voice-artist,#creative-director
1               #designer,#asistant
```

Your Solution, just `regex` implied ..

```
>>> df["description"] = df["description"].str.replace("#", "", regex=True)
>>> df["description"] = df["description"].str.replace(",", ", ", regex=True)
>>> df
                       description
0  voice-artist, creative-director
1               designer, asistant
```

OR:

Try using [Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) instead. It can be useful if you need to replace a substring.

```
>>> df["description"] = df["description"].str.replace("#", "")
>>> df["description"] = df["description"].str.replace(",", ", ")
>>> df
                       description
0  voice-artist, creative-director
1               designer, asistant
```